# How to get saved data from html file?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

I have some data saved inside the html file, which looks like this:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.__data = {
     id: 1,
     text: 'Test blob',
  };
  </script>
</body>
```

the data  is saved locally inside the `data.html` file.
Now, I'm trying to load the data into a separate `app.js` file:

I initially tried accessing the `document` directly:

```
const getData = () => console.log(document.__data);
```

But that jsut returns as `undefined` so then I tried the following:

```
 // app.js
 const getData = async () => {
     const request = await fetch('./data.html');
     const data = await request.json();
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
 }

 getData();
```

But that just returns the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: Is this external `.js` file included in the html or do you want to parse the html file and get the data? Because with the way you do, you get whole html content and try to parse it. Therefore the error occurs.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz it is. But it doesn't really matter as to which way the data is extracted, I'm just more of curious how to access the data available inside html file

Comment: Actually it matters. If the `.js` file is included and you assign `__data` property to `document`, you can simply access it by using `const getData = () => {return document.__data}`. By using `fetch`, you make an XHR request to `./data.html` url and it returns the whole html content.

Comment: Well, of course HTML is not a valid JSON.

Comment: As mentioned, you can't do `JSON.stringify(data)` on HTML content, `data` will hold the HTML code, e.g. try `console.log(data);`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Could you perhaps elaborate, because I did try exactly the same you suggested in your last comment, but that just returned `undefined`, so I assumed I can't reference`document` directly, tried `fetch` and hence posted this question

Comment: You can look at this [plunker project](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Zmz5jGkOv8eUH4J6?preview). In your case, it is returning `undefined` because you call `getData()` before you assign `__data` property to `document`. You either need to call it after assigning or wait for document to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, adding custom, arbitrary properties to the `document` is not recommended, as in:

```
document.__data = { ... };
```

instead do something like e.g.

```
var data = { ... };
```

---

Now, assuming you want to access the inline data using an external `app.js` file, that file needs to be loaded *after* your inline one, or else it will come back `undefined`.

So this is how it needs to look like in your HTML:

```
<head>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    var data = {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Test blob',
   };
  </script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
```

And your `app.js`

```
const getData = () => console.log(data);

getData();
```

---

If your external `app.js` loads within the `head`, as in your original HTML, you need to delay the `getData()` until the DOM is ready, and this is how it needs to look like in your `app.js`:

```
const getData = () => console.log(data);

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

    getData();

});
```

And the reason is simply that you can't access what comes later in the document as it is not loaded yet, hence the `undefined` issue in your first sample.

---

Below two snippets use inline script so you can see how it works. Just replace the `getData()` part with your `app.js` and it will work as well.

Showing it does work when [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) is finished.

```html
<head>
      <script>
        const getData = () => console.log(data);

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

            getData();

        });
      </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <script>
        var data = {
          id: 1,
          text: 'Test blob',
        };
      </script>
      
    </body>
```

Showing it does not work when not delayed until DOM is finished

```html
<head>
      <script>
        const getData = () => console.log(data);

        getData();        
      </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <script>
        var data = {
          id: 1,
          text: 'Test blob',
        };
      </script>
      
    </body>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Yeah, it wouldn't be my choice to store the data inside a `.html` file either, but it's not up to me. I'm still somewhat confused tho, the external file is `.js` file and in your answer you are recommending the html `<script>` tag. Is there a way I could import the data to a pure `.js` file (no html involved)

Comment: @Rawrplus I already wrote how-to, were you put the same code in above snippet in a `js` file. And I do not recommend inline `<script>`, I only used it in the above sample so it could be executed.

Comment: @Rawrplus I might have misunderstood what you actually asked. I edited my answer, and hopefully I got it right this time.

Comment: It's fine, actually you got it somewhat right the first time, least enough for me to figure out the answer, issue was, since my app was in react, the page was not being properly referenced despite the fact the `src=''` was properly pointing to `app.js` I just copied the code from `data.html` to `index.html` and then was able to access the properties. 

Either way, I do concur I could have phrased the question better and accepted it hence it's pretty well structured answer to the broad question I provided

Comment: @Rawrplus -- Ok, great. Should I leave the answer as it is now, or should I roll it back? Let me know which is better.

Comment: My case was more specific to react which is not mentioned in the question. Yours answers it in more general terms so leave it as it is I guess :)